# Error in `./px': free(): invalid next size (normal)Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, memory, realloc

Hello i was looking  for a solution in many discussions ,unfortunantly  without getting anything helpful.

I have a proxy server that take a request from one client and ask for a response from the server,  the step I  follow are:

**1-->** i made a request from the  client to the proxy.

**2-->**  the proxy connect to the server and send  a response to the client (until here every thing works well).

**3-->** when i made a second request from the same client to the proxy,when the proxy try to connect a second time to the server this error occurs:

> *** Error in `./px': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0000000001941120 Aborted (core dumped) ***

here is the method where the error occur:

```
char * readResponseFromServer(char *hostname,char *request,char *response){
int sock;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct hostent * server;

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(sock<0)
    printEror("socket opening error");

server=gethostbyname(hostname);

if (server == NULL)
      printEror ("unknown host");
printf("the server adress is  %s\n",server->h_name);

bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
     (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
     server->h_length);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(80);


if(connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
     {
            printEror("connection error");

    }
int n1 = write(sock,request,strlen(request));
if (n1< 0) 
        printEror("ERROR writing to socket");
//reading response from server
int readed=0;
int bytesloaded=0;
int buf_size=512;
//we try to read 256 bytes each time
while( (readed = read(sock, response+ bytesloaded, buf_size)) > 0 )
    {   

    if(bytesloaded + readed >= buf_size)//the response buffer is full , so we allocate more memory
    {
        buf_size = buf_size + 256;  
        response = (char *)realloc(response, buf_size);

    }
    bytesloaded += readed;
    }

printf("the response is: %s",response);
close(sock);
```

}

and especially in this call:

```
    server=gethostbyname(hostname);
```

to sum up i get this error when i call the method above more than on time.

why i get this error?

Many thanks.

**Solution:**

I used the different suggestions to solve my problem, and I thank you once again.

the main problem was:

1. a deallocation of memory problem with the free() method .
2. a bad way to reallocate memory.

and the error was not in the Methode I posted  but in  another method despite that the program stops elsewhere, so it's one thing i have learned with this problem : the memory error could come from anywhere in your program.

so I had to review my program and I managed to find out where was the error memory.

Comment: `response = (char *)realloc(response, buf_size);` :: too little, too late.

Comment: hello wildplasser , i didn't get what do you mean , thanks

Comment: He means, you overwrite the buffer first, then try to extend it after the fact. You should make sure to only read as many bytes as you have space available and grow the buffer if you don't have enough space before you try to read into it.

Comment: Also the memory is initially provided by the caller. realloc()ing here is a (potential) memory leak. (realloc can return a  pointer different from its 1st argument )

Comment: If the buffer needs to grow while in the called function, then you need to pass the buffer's address, not the buffer itself.  This will allow the called function to grow the buffer if needed while allowing the calling function to retain the ability to free it when it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Error in `./px': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0000000001941120 Aborted (core dumped) *

In your code, assuming memory for `char *request` variable used in the following prototype:

```
char * readResponseFromServer(char *hostname,char *request,char *response){
```

is provided and freed from within the calling function...
...Then, if it is required that the buffer's memory be changed in the called function, the caller must pass the *address of* the variable, not the variable itself.  In this way, `realloc()` can be used in the called function, while providing the caller ability to free the memory.  Here is a snippet showing how this works using `realloc()`:

```
void growBuffer(char ** b, int *size);//note prototype include char **, not char *

int main(void) 
{ 
    char *buf = {0};
    buf = calloc(20,1);
    strcpy(buf, "original string-");
    int len = strlen(buf)+1;
    printf("Original buf and length: %s - %d\n", buf, len);
    growBuffer(&buf, &len);//caller passes address of buf: (&buf) 
    printf("New buf and length: %s - %d\n", buf, len);
    free(buf);//caller can now safely free memory

    return 0;
}



void growBuffer(char **buffer, int *size)
{
    const char newContent[]={"new content requires growing buffer"};

    int newlen = *size + strlen(newContent) + 1;

    char *buf = realloc((*buffer), newlen );
    if(buf)//always test return of [m][c][re]alloc before using
    {
        (*buffer) = buf; //assign new memory to buffer
        strcat((*buffer), newContent);//modify string
        *size = newlen;//pass back new len of string
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you ,may be it's a one problem in my code .what i did to resolve the first error above i have reviewed my program  to free every variable that i had allocated memory, and the problem is solved now,so i will rewrite my program to fit your suggestion.many thanks